# How to increase you tube quota where it allow only 10k per day

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have developed a news website. Partners are allowed to submit articles (video articles) via a dedicated form. We want the videos to be hosted on Youtube then embedded on the website. We have a working prototype. The problem is the Youtube API Quota. Youtube offers 10k units per day. An upload costs 1600, which basically means after 6 videos, we can't use the API.

We've tried to click on the button to increase the quota from the console, but the max value is 10k (which makes no sense btw). We've filled the dedicated form multiple time, we've contacted our former Youtube sales guy who said couldn't help. We even managed to have a Google representative on the phone who said he didn't know how it works and that we should discuss that with Youtube directly.

Does anyone know how to proceed? We're willing to pay the extra units, but even for that, we can't find the proper procedure. Most of websites and threads dealing with the issue are old one when quotas were very high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://console.developers.google.com/ -> library -> search for YouTube Data -> click manage button  -> click quota menu -> click quota page link -> click a quota and select edit quota at the top.

A panel will open on the side

[image]

You can apply for 10k more but its going to take some time.  It took me three months to get an extension of 10k

Comment: Thanks a lots for your answer of my query.
can we buy this ? 
there is any plan & prize list to buy this.

Comment: @DalmTo I had a few questions about when you got your quota increased. Did you have to have a completed project and send that to them with your application? I want to get my quota increased, but it seems like a hassle after going over the application since my project isn't completed yet. I'm worried about putting lots of work into it and end up getting denied or not qualifying for enough quota. My 2nd question is, how much did they increase your quota to? Would appreciate any tips. Thanks!

Comment: They increased it by 10k,  Well if you wait until you are done and it takes 3 -6 months to here if you can get an increase thats going to be a long delay I would think.   But they may want to see your application working.

Comment: It took around 2 months, but mine got increased. Be prepared to show your app running within a secure (https) domainname server.